# Hazelcast Jet connector for Apache Pulsar as source

Tags: hazelcast-jet, apache-pulsar

I could not find a `Hazlecast Jet` source connector for `Apache Pulsar`. Have anybody tried this? Appreciate any directions, points, sources, considerations if I have to write a custom `stream` connector for `Pulsar` as source for Jet?

Comment: I establish a Pulsar connection & consumer in SourceBuilder.timestampedStream, add messages (consumer.receive(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) read from PulsarConsumer to buffer on fillBufferFn, finally, closing the consumer & connection to Pulsar on destroyFn. It worked. However, how to handle the createSnapshotFn & restoreSnapshotFn? As I havent worked much on Kafka, I am not quite able to link similar approach in Pulsar. Any references?

Comment: `createSnapshotFn` should return the current message cursor so it will be stored and `restoreSnapshotFn ` should restore the cursor and set it to the client to consume messages from where it left off.

Answer (score 2):

The initial version of the Jet connector for Apache Pulsar is recently implemented [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-contrib/pull/44). It hasn't been extensively tested yet. For details, you can look at the [design document](https://jet-start.sh/docs/next/design-docs/009-pulsar-connector) in which the connector's sufficiencies and deficiencies stated, and [tutorial](https://jet-start.sh/docs/next/tutorials/pulsar). If there is anything confusing about these, you can ask again.

Comment: Thanks Ufuk, I will do a use case implementation with Pulsar in a Jet job.

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast Jet doesn't have any connector for Apache Pulsar as of now (version 4.0). If you'd like to contribute one you can have a look at the [Source Builder](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/3.2.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/jet/pipeline/SourceBuilder.html) class and its [section](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/3.2.1/manual/#source-sink-builder) on the reference manual as a starting point.

Also, please check out existing implementations of various connectors at the [Hazelcast Jet extension modules](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-contrib) repository which uses source builder API and contribute yours to there.

Comment: I wrote a pulsar-source keeping Kafka-connect as reference. The problem I face is, if I use Pulsar `reader` to read pulsar messages, in absense of this reader any message written to Pulsar are not read, but any new incoming message are read. Also, if the job is restarted this approach do not reread all messages from the start. In another approach, if I use pulsar `consumer`, everytime the Jet job is restarted it always starts from the first due to messages not acknowledged, so no messages are left unprocessed, but possible chance of duplicate processing. Any comments?

Comment: You should use Pulsar Reader interface with user provided start point in the beginning. If Jet snapshots are enabled then it should store the current message id and when there is a failure it need to restore message id from the snapshot. According to [Pulsar Reader](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-clients/#non-partitioned-topics-only) documentation, you can use it only for non-partitioned topics.

Comment: So, in that case the snapshot have to be persisted? Consider situations where the streaming app can be cold rebooted.

Comment: Hazelcast Jet stores the snapshot data in a [Hazelcast IMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.5/manual/html-single/index.html#map) which keeps the data in-memory. With the [Lossless Cluster Restart](https://hazelcast.com/product-features/lossless-cluster-restart/) feature the data can be persisted to a disk.